# SQL: IF age in "age" column greater than 20 INSERT record into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, ssis

I have a SSIS package that pulls data from reports and loads into SQL-Server.  I need to write another package that tests the `"Age"` column of that table.  `IF the age is greater than 20` then I need to `INSERT` that record into another table while keeping the same record in the same table.

What is the best approach to do this while keeping the logic withing the SSIS objects?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both tables have same schema,

```
Insert into targetTable
Select * 
From sourceTable
Where Age>20
```

Comment: Thanks...I just also found the `Conditional Split` transformation in `SSIS`